# Console App launched from windows service has no file system access

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file, service

I have a windows service that is designed to launch several console applications.  The console applications will write to a physical log file as well as file system operations.

When the service launches the consoles, they have no access to the file system and nothing appears in the log files.

When I launch the console's manually by double clicking on the executables, they have no issues writing to the log files.

I have tried running the service under local system, local service, network service, the local administrator account and even my own login credentials:

This is the code that launches the processes:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = agent.AgentLocation; /// Physical path to executable
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.Start();
```

Comment: Not specifying ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory is always a good way to lose files.  Look in c:\windows\system32

Comment: Also don't forget about the UAC if you're working on a modern windows box. But I think Hans nailed it.

Comment: Are you sure that the console apps are started? Set the `CreateNoWindow=false` to see what's happening in the console.

Comment: I will try setting th working directory but the consoles write to a completely seperate folder defined elsewhere.  thanks for the advice

Comment: The console apps are started as I can see them in Task Manager.   I am in the process of implementing logging to a database.

Comment: are you getting an exception? can you post details here?

Comment: Thanks for the help!  It turned out that you MUST set the working directory on the process.  I'm not sure the logic but that turned out to be the fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

The problem turned out that you need to set the working directory as follows:

```
Process p = new Process(); 
p.StartInfo.FileName = agent.AgentLocation; /// Physical path to executable 
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(agent.AgentLocation);
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
p.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false; 
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; 
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; 
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
p.Start();
```